# How to fix/set column width in a django modeladmin change list table when a list_filter is added?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm working on improving the admin.py in a django project, and while I'm not totally jazzed about how the table was coming out with three fields in the list_diplay, at least it's better than just getting a default object list with one column spanning the whole page...

Anyway,  what I'm asking is why if this:

```
class FieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'label', 'standard',  )
```

looks like this:

[image: without list_filter]

When I add a list_filter, like this:

```
class FieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'label', 'standard',  )
    list_filter = ['standard',]
```

Why does it look like this?

[image: Imgur]

Is there a way to get the columns to re-grow to fill the width like it was prior to adding the filter?   I've been reading the docs and googling, but it doesn't seem built in?  The project I'm working on is currently using django 1,2,3,final.

FWIW, the css that causes this is here:

```
.change-list .filtered table, .change-list .filtered .paginator, 
.filtered #toolbar, .filtered div.xfull {
    margin-right: 160px !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

disabling the width style specification fixes it, but I'd rather do things the django way if there is one - I was hoping maybe there's a way to customize the filter view from the FieldAdmin class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to refer to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

basically, the change_list.html needs to be overridden .

you can do it this way:

```
templates/
  admin/
    app/
      change_list.html
```

you can obtain a copy of change_list.html from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/`

and update the css the way you desire.

Comment: I realize it's not a huge deal in the scheme of things, but it seems extreme for such a small thing (I'm not blaming you obviously, it's just disappointing ;-)

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 5):

admin.py:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('fancy.css')
        }
```

fancy.css:

```
.column-foo {
    width: 20px;
}
```

where "foo" is a field name.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/media/